# Bagging in R - How do I obtain the bagged regression in order to compare it to the initial model?

Tags: r, aggregate, data-modeling

I'm trying to obtain the linear regression models before the bagging and after the bagging. How would I do this? And how would I bag each model separately?

I would like to have 6 models for my six independent variables (everything but y) that I could compare (after bagging) to my intial models.

I've tried cutting down my sample set to only the y and k variables but it didn't work. I also tried changing the divisor length but that didn't affect my desired outcome.

```
### First Part ###
y<-c(3.687,6.267,5.778,6.041,4.968,5.934)
k<-c(8.8,18,15,16.7,12.3,16.6)
g<-c(6.6,19,15.3,18.5,10,19.6)
c<-c(10.5,17.2,16,15.5,14.2,14.8)
s<-c(9.4,19.5,15.8,17.6,11.6,18)
a<-c(7,18.4,14.2,17.2,9.6,17.6)
b<-c(8.5,18.4,15.3,17.1,11.5,17.3)
lm_fit<-lm(y~k+g+c+s+a+b)
summary(lm_fit)
### Second Part ###
all_data<-data.frame(y,k,g,c,s,a,b)
positions <- sample(nrow(all_data),size=floor((nrow(all_data)/4)*3))
training<- all_data[positions,]
testing<- all_data[-positions,]
lm_fit<-lm(y~k+g+c+s+a+b,data=training)
predictions<-predict(lm_fit,newdata=testing)
error<-sqrt((sum((testing$y-predictions)^2))/nrow(testing))
### Third Part ###
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
length_divisor<-3
iterations<-100
predictions<-foreach(m=1:iterations,.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
training_positions <- sample(nrow(training), size=floor((nrow(training)/length_divisor)))
train_pos<-1:nrow(training) %in% training_positions
lm_fit<-lm(y~k+g+c+s+a+b,data=training[train_pos,])
predict(lm_fit,newdata=testing)
}
predictions<-rowMeans(predictions)
error<-sqrt((sum((testing$y-predictions)^2))/nrow(testing))
stopCluster(cl)
```

I expected to have 6 line models initially, in the first segment of code which worked as expected but after bagging I only have 1 model? And I don't have any way of comparing the models to one another as there isn't any r value or p value produced to validate them, simply an ambiguous error value. Would anybody be nice enough to help me out? Thank you!!